# Union of multiple queries using the count function

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, union

I'm working on learning more about how the `UNION` function works in SQL Server.

I've got a query that is directed at a single table:

```
SELECT Category, COUNT(*) AS Number
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Category;
```

This returns the number of entries for each distinct line in the `Category` column.

I have multiple tables that are organized by this `Category` column and I'd like to be able to have the results for every table returned by one query.

It seems like `UNION` will accomplish what I want it to do but the way I've tried implementing the query doesn't work with `COUNT(*)`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Table1.Category
               Table1.COUNT(*) AS Number
        FROM   dbo.Table1
        UNION
        SELECT Table2.Category
               Table2.COUNT(*) AS Number
        FROM   dbo.Table2) AS a
GROUP  BY a.Category
```

I'm sure there's an obvious reason why this doesn't work but can anyone point out what that is and how I could accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write a common `Group by` clause for two different `select's`. You need to use `Group by` clause for each `select`

```
SELECT TABLE1.Category, --missing comma here
       COUNT(*) as Number -- Remove TABLE1. alias name
FROM dbo.TABLE1
GROUP BY Category
UNION ALL --UNION
SELECT TABLE2.Category, --missing comma here
       COUNT(*) as Number -- Remove TABLE1. alias name
FROM dbo.TABLE2
GROUP BY Category
```

If you really want to remove duplicates in result then change `UNION ALL` to `UNION`

Comment: I still get the same error. `Incorrect syntax near '*'`

Comment: @Neal Copy paste my query and execute it you will never get that error. There is a missing comma after `Table1.category`

Comment: I did the first time and I did it just now again and the same error occurred.

Comment: @Neal - My bad check now

Comment: That did it. I could have sworn I had tried `count(*)` without the `Table1.` prefix but obviously not. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

COUNT as any associated aggregation function has to have GROUP BY specified. You have to use group by for each sub query separately:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TABLE1.Category,
           COUNT(*) as Number
    FROM dbo.TABLE1
    GROUP BY TABLE1.Category
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TABLE2.Category,
           COUNT(*) as Number
    FROM dbo.TABLE2
    GROUP BY TABLE2.Category
) as a
```

It is better to use UNION ALL vs UNION - UNION eliminates duplicates from result sets, since - let say - you want to merge both results as they are it is safer to use UNION ALL

Comment: I still get the same error. `Incorrect syntax near '*'`

Comment: Missed that one. COUNT is sql server function, not part of a table. You do not use TABLE1.COUNT(*), but you could use COUNT(TABLE1.*)

Comment: I replaced `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(TABLE1.)`:

`Incorrect syntax near ')'`

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a typo it should be COUNT(TABLE1.*)

Comment: By the way, once you learn to read syntax description on MSDN you can write everything :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

Comment: There were also missing commas.

Comment: Commas are there and `COUNT(*) vs COUNT(TABLE1.*)` is how I did it originally when it didn't work.